# EC2 mount point with s3fs and using role_arn and source_profile

Tags: amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have multiple buckets that can be accessed with the same AWS User.

I have no problem listing the files using AWS Cli, but first I had to configure a profile using AWS Cli and also include the parameters 'role_arn' and 'source_profile' on my .aws/config file.

Is there any special grant that this role must have?

I am trying to mount these buckets on my EC2 instance using 's3fs-fuse', tried everything i.e: -o profile=my-profile but it doesn't work, the command doesn't drop any error, even including -d or --debug.